Vega of forward volatility
Imagine I have two European-style options that are the same except for their times to expiry: $T_1 \lt T_2$. And each option has its own vega $\mathcal{V}_1$ and $\mathcal{V}_2$. My question is: what is the vega of the forward volatility between $T_1$ and $T_2$?
For example, if $T_2=2$, $T_1=1$, $\mathcal{V}_1 = 1000$, and $\mathcal{V}_1 = 500$, then intuitively, the vega between the two expiries should be very roughly \$250. The intuition being that the other $\\\$250$ is before $T_1$. But clearly it's not linear in general, and it's also not quite square-root-time since B-S vega contains $d_1$, which itself is a function of time.
